# How to connect to AWS RDS external database (not for the core WordPress db)

Tags: plugin-development, database, mysql, amazon

I'm trying to connect to an external database on AWS RDS to display data from the external database in WordPress, using a plugin I'm writing.

My only issue is connecting to the external database and pulling information from it.

Additionally, I need to be able to update info in the external database as well.

I'm trying to use `$awsdb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database', 'localhost' );` but it doesn't seem to be working.

RDS has slightly different access details to a regular MySQL db, and I'm unfamiliar with RDS.

The details I have to work with are:

```
adapter: mysql
encoding: utf8
database: database_name
username: username
password: password
host: thedatabase.0000000000.location-1.rds.amazonaws.com
port: 0000
```

I have been placing the info in how I thought would be correct:

`$awsdb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database_name', 'thedatabase.0000000000.location-1.rds.amazonaws.com' );`

but that doesn't seem to work.

I also tried it with the port appended:

`$awsdb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database_name', 'thedatabase.0000000000.location-1.rds.amazonaws.com:0000' );`

I'm kinda lost on this trivial piece to the puzzle.

Here is the function I'm testing by trying to display a list of the stored usernames in the external table:

```
function test_connect_to_db() {
    $awsdb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database_name', 'thedatabase.0000000000.location-1.rds.amazonaws.com' );
    $rows = $awsdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table"  );
    echo '<div style="clear:both;text-align:center;"><h1>DB DETAILS</h1></div>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($rows as $obj) {
        echo '<li>'.$obj->user_id.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

}
add_action( 'init', 'test_connect_to_db' );
```

Note: I have omitted actual connection credentials and used placeholder text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a working connection using the following code:

```
function test_connect_to_db() {

    $servername = 'thedatabase.0000000000.location-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $dbname = 'database';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

    // Check connection
    if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
        die( 'Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error );
    } 

    $sql = 'SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM table';
    $result = $conn->query( $sql );

    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
    // output data of each row
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            echo '<br> id: '. $row['id']. ' - Name: '. $row['firstname']. ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '0 results';
    }

    $conn->close();

}
add_action( 'init', 'test_connect_to_db' );
```